# How to get a URL from a route in Startup.Auth?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to get a url to a login page, in my Startup.Auth I have:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString( ... )
});
```

How can I retrieve the url to the login page (controller = "Login", action = "Index")?

I do not have an `UrlHelper` object to use `Action` method...

Comment: @DJKRAZE: There is no request.

Comment: I have the same issue as well..